# Query std::mutex for lock state

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I have a situation where I'd like to do something like that shown below, but there doesn't seem to be a way of querying the mutex without changing its state. I don't want the `someFunctionCalledRepeatedlyFromAnotherThread()` to hang around waiting for the mutex to free up if it is locked. It must return immediately after performing some alternative action. I'm guessing this omission is there for safety, as the lock may free up in the time between querying it and the function returning. In my case, bad stuff will not happen if the lock is freed while `doSomeAlternativeAction()` is happening. The fact I'm in this situation probably means I'm doing something wrong, so how should I change my design?

```
class MyClass 
{
    std::mutex initMutex;
public:
    void someInitializationFunction()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(initMutex);
        // Do some work
    }

    void someFunctionCalledRepeatedlyFromAnotherThread()
    {
        if (initMutex.isLocked()) 
        {
            doSomeAlternativeAction();
            return;
        }
        // otherwise . . .
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(initMutex);
        // carry on with work as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use [std::mutex::try_lock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/try_lock/).

Comment: . . . but that changes the state of the mutex.

Comment: @learnvst But only if the mutex is not locked, and such case, your code changes its state as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Asking mutex for its state is useless: it may be unlocked now, but by the time you get around to lock it, it may be locked. So it does not have such method.

It does, however, have a method [`try_lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) which locks it if it is not locked and returns `true` if it acquired the lock and `false` otherwise. And [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) (the more advanced version of `std::lock_guard`) has option to call it.

So you can do:

```
void someFunctionCalledRepeatedlyFromAnotherThread()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(initMutex, std::try_to_lock);
    if(!lock.owns_lock())
    {
        doSomeAlternativeAction();
        return;
    }
    // otherwise ... go ahead, you have the lock
}
```

Comment: If try_lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined. according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock

Comment: @camino, just like calling `lock` in that case. `std::mutex` is not recursive, and its behaviour on attempts to lock it recursively, either way, is not defined so it can be implemented using primitives with different recursive behaviour on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use std::unique_lock instead of std::lock_guard. The try_lock method works similar to the TryEnterCriticalSection on Windows, whereby the function will atomically acquire the lock and return 'true' if it can, or just return 'false' if the lock cannot be acquired (and will not block). Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921439.aspx and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/try_lock. Note that unique_lock also has other members available for trying to lock such as try_lock_for and try_lock_until.